# WPF ComboBox SelectedItem when bound to an enum

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, enums

I have a WPF ComboBox bound to a list of a class which contains an enum.

This all works fine, my question is at the end of this post, first the code:

Here is the class:

```
public class FILTER_TEST
{
    public FilterType Filter { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public static List<FILTER_TEST> CreateFilters()
    {
        var list = new List<FILTER_TEST>();

        list.Add(new FILTER_TEST() { Filter = FilterType.CheckNone, Description = "Uncheck all" });
        list.Add(new FILTER_TEST() { Filter = FilterType.CheckAll, Description = "Check all" });
        list.Add(new FILTER_TEST() { Filter = FilterType.CheckCustom, Description = "Custom check" });

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is the enum FilterType:

```
public enum FilterType
{
    CheckNone,
    CheckAll,
    CheckCustom
}
```

In my view model I have the following:

```
public List<FILTER_TEST> FilterNames { get { return FILTER_TEST.CreateFilters(); } }

public FILTER_TEST SelectedFilter
{
    get { return selectedFilter; }
    set
    {
        if (value != selectedFilter)
        {
            selectedFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFilter");
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the view model, I set the SelectedItem of the ComboBox as follows:

```
SelectedFilter = FilterNames.Where(x => x.Filter == FilterType.CheckNone).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is the xaml putting it all together:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterNames}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

My problem is that although the changing of the SelectionItem works, the *actual value displayed in the ComboBox doesn’t change*.

The initial SelectedItem is “Uncheck all” as, when the window has been loaded, none of the corresponding CheckBox controls (bound to another class which contains a Boolean property) have been checked. What I would like is that when a CheckBox has been checked, then the SelectedItem changes to “Custom check”.

This does indeed change the value of the SelectedItem:

```
SelectedFilter = FilterNames.Where(x => x.Filter == FilterType.CheckCustom).FirstOrDefault();
```

But the text shown in the ComboBox is still “Uncheck all”.

Does anyone have an idea as to what I am missing? I am forced to use the 4.0 framework, I don’t know if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the hint to overwrite `Equals()` of the type in use as this:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
      if (o is FILTER_TEST)
      {
           var other = o as FILTER_TEST;
           return this.Description == other.Description && this.Filter == other.Filter;
      }
      else
           return false;
}
```

Now that makes your sample work. Let me come back for a reference on the *why*.

Comment: Thank you! With your help I found this from Rachel Lim: [Rachels link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/comboboxs-selecteditem-not-displaying/) Your tip and Rachels site got this to work, Very much appreciated, consider this accepted!

Comment: Glad to help, I do understand the problem, but not the cause. Why is the `SelectedItem` not of the same reference? It is the same underlying `List<FILTER_TEST>`, no?

Comment: To be honest I also thought that the _SelectedItem_ was using the same reference. I saw another post from @Sheridan as to how to set the item from the same source which is why I thought my problem was another one.

Comment: Actually the call to `return FILTER_TEST.CreateFilters();` creates a new list each time it is called, so there goes our reference.